# Cross platform compiling using CeGCC

Tags: winapi, arm, cross-compiling, windows-ce

I am trying to compile a C program using CeGCC, the program is written in C using Win32 API, and it's being compiled with MingW like this:

`gcc -o "Win32App.exe" obj/winmain.o obj/callbacks.o obj/resource.o -s -lcomctl32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows`

As a result the program is successfully compiled and then tested afterwards. The problem occurs when i try to compile it for ARM (Windows-CE) rather than x86-based architecture:

```
obj/winmain.o:winmain.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to InitCommonControlsEx
obj/winmain.o:winmain.c:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to RegisterClassExW
```

As you can see the problem is that the two functions called [InitCommonControlsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775697(v=vs.85).aspx) and [RegisterClassExW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587(v=vs.85).aspx) are not defined in Windows-CE.

My Question is how can i find an equivalent function to use in my code so that i can successfully compile and run my program in Windows-CE. I need help in replacing those two functions with compatible ones which are recognized in CeGCC.

Comment: You can find CeGCC project at [SourceForge](http://www.cegcc.sourceforge.net), also the source code of the mentioned program (winmain.c) can be found at [TransmissionZero](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/win32-apps-with-mingw/)

Comment: [`InitCommonControlsEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms909849.aspx) actually is available for Windows CE, but as you can see from the reference, you need to link to a different library (Commctrl.lib). `RegisterClassEx()` is not available, but it's not a big deal because `WNDCLASSEX` only adds the member `hIconSm`. So just use `RegisterClass()` instead. If this works for you, I'll turn that into an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your useful input, i have tried your solution as much as i could, i used `RegisterClass()` instead of `RegisterClassEx()` which solved half of the problem. However about the other half i am still having problem with linking to Commctrl.lib since i am not using any IDE and i don't know how to link it to my code or where to download the .lib file in the first place.

Comment: Try to add gcc switch `-lcommctrl`. You already have `-lcomctl32` so it seems like you have the libraries in place.

Comment: That's the thing, i have been searching through the web for the solution but it seems that i don't have ComCtl32.lib nor do i have Commctrl.lib, and if i do it seems that i am unable to resolve their location and link them successfully at compile time, would it be possible to download them both and link them to my code when compiling? (Keep in mind that i am cross compiling my program using CeGCC which means any library needs to conform to the corresponding architecture which is ARM-32)

Comment: Quick Update: Let's assume i can get my hands on [comctl32.dll](http://www.jasinskionline.com/windowsapi/ref/i/initcommoncontrolsex.html), would it help to link it to my program when compiling with MingW? If so, how can i link this .dll file at compile time?